# Generating allure reporting using testNG or ATU xml or results

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml, allure

The automation framework that we have stores the test method names included in spreadsheet to the db table. Another piece of the framework picks the test methods from the db and executes them. And hence there is nothing I could include in "include" of "configuration". A testNG xml/report and ATU report gets generated at the end of the test execution. Is there a way I could use the either of these reports to generate a allure report?

Comment: Do you want to generate allure report from existing testng report?

Comment: Yes, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Allure Reports for TestNG, Generates high level executive reporting. Add following dependencies to the POM file.

```
    <dependency>
           <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
           <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
          <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Run the mvn site command and after successful build, go to workspace.(Your Project Name).\target\site\allure-maven-plugin and double click on index.html file.
For further details, go to their official website and github. This will help.